# ConcreteA is not abstract and does not override abstract method doSomething(InterfaceA) in InterfaceC

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
interface InterfaceA {}

interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA {

}

interface InterfaceC {
    public void doSomething(InterfaceA t);
}

class ConcreteA implements InterfaceC {
    public void doSomething(InterfaceB t)    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

`ConcreteA is not abstract and does not override abstract method insert(InterfaceA) in InterfaceC`

Now, my understanding is because InterfaceB extends from InterfaceA, I should be able to use InterfaceB in a function which requires InterfaceA, but this is not the case. Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and point me in the right direction to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly let us know how `ConcreteB` is defined

Comment: Excuse me, I had an excess ConcreteA in the example originally. I edited my question with the right error. Edit: Fixed it now @TraianGEICU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But method signature of ConcreteA is different than the interface declaration.
Java compiler expects exactly InterfaceA passed to `doSomething` method.

You need to either change it to a valid one:

```
class ConcreteA implements InterfaceC {
    public void doSomething(InterfaceA t)    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Above declaration doesn't prevent you from passing an object that implements InterfaceB as an argument, but the method declaration must match `InterfaceC` definition.

Or support with a generic type:

```
interface  InterfaceC <T extends InterfaceA>  {
     void doSomething(T t);
}

class ConcreteA implements InterfaceC<InterfaceB> {
    public void doSomething(InterfaceB t)    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a real lifesaver!!! Disregard my previous comment. It works now!